# Pandas rule based column merging

Tags: python, pandas, pubmed

I have a dataset with articles from `pubmed`. DataFrame looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"section_names":[["introduction","methods","section1","another section","discussion"],
                                ["introduction","methods","discussion","other section","one  more section","conclusion"]],
               "sections":[[["intro text","another sentence"],["some text","some text", "more text"],["some text","some text"],["some text","some text"],["some text","some text"]],
                          [["intro text","another sentence"],["some text","some text"],["some text","more text","some text","more text"],["some text","some text"],["some text","some text"],["some text","some text"]]]})
```

So basically, the column `section_names` has has name of all the sections in an article. In column "sections", there is actual text in a list for each section names in `section_names`. As a first step I wanted to have each section in a column. So, I did this:

```
df_col = pd.DataFrame([dict(zip(*pair)) for pair in zip(df['section_names'], df['sections'])]):
```

[image: resulting dataframe]

The Value `NaN` makes sense because those section are not available for the particular column, for each column there will be at least one non NaN value. For a lot of articles with different section names, the number of columns will increase drastically. In the original dataset, I actually have around 10,000 columns.

What I now want is to merge the columns and have max 4 columns (Introduction, methods, discussion, conclusion). I want to say something like:

> After a section name `methods`, merge all other sections until
> `discussion` with `methods` and after `methods` merge all until
> `conclusion` with `discussion`

With this rule in our `df`, for first article, `section1` and `another section` will be merged with `methods`. For second article, `other section` and `one more section` should be merged with `discussion`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a column index based on where the desired columns are, then aggregate the rows of each group into lists:

```
desired_columns = ['introduction', 'methods', 'discussion', 'conclusion']
new_df = df.groupby(df.columns.isin(desired_columns).cumsum(), axis=1).agg(
    lambda x: x.agg(
        lambda r: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(r.dropna()))
                  or np.nan,
        axis=1)
)
new_df.columns = desired_columns
```

`new_df`:

```
                     introduction                                                                        methods                                                                                discussion              conclusion
0  [intro text, another sentence]  [some text, some text, more text, some text, some text, some text, some text]                                                                    [some text, some text]                     NaN
1  [intro text, another sentence]                                                         [some text, some text]  [some text, more text, some text, more text, some text, some text, some text, some text]  [some text, some text]
```

The column index is created using:

```
df.columns.isin(desired_columns).cumsum()
```

Which produces groups like:

```
[1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4]
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import itertools

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "section_names": [
        ["introduction", "methods", "section1", "anothersection", "discussion"],
        ["introduction", "methods", "discussion", "othersection",
         "onemoresection", "conclusion"]], "sections": [
        [["introtext", "anothersentence"], ["sometext", "sometext", "moretext"],
         ["sometext", "sometext"], ["sometext", "sometext"],
         ["sometext", "sometext"]],
        [["introtext", "anothersentence"], ["sometext", "sometext"],
         ["sometext", "moretext", "sometext", "moretext"],
         ["sometext", "sometext"], ["sometext", "sometext"],
         ["sometext", "sometext"]]]
})

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [dict(zip(*pair)) for pair in zip(df['section_names'], df['sections'])])

desired_columns = ['introduction', 'methods', 'discussion', 'conclusion']
new_df = df.groupby(df.columns.isin(desired_columns).cumsum(), axis=1).agg(
    lambda x: x.agg(
        lambda r: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(r.dropna()))
                  or np.nan,
        axis=1)
)
new_df.columns = desired_columns
print(new_df.to_string())
```